# How fast can a Transformer run?

Tags: transformers

We see them transform from their vehicular form to their "bipedal" form on the move numerous times in the movies. Several of these transformations happen at highway speeds (say 60-70 mph). Has it ever been established how fast they can actually run on foot? Obviously some would be faster than others so I'm looking for the fastest established or estimated foot speed.

Comment: It depends how many times they're contractually obliged to stop in front of a billboard.

Comment: European or African Transformer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt if anyone has ever measured his speed, but Blurr is widely recognized as one of the fastest (if not *the* fastest) Transformer on foot. He's been described as being faster than the speed of sound on foot and clocking 800 MPH in vehicle mode.

[image: Blurr]

Answer (score -1):

Animated blur ran the galaxy from jupiter to earth to cybertron in less than a minute. He is probably the fastest blurr, with G1 blurr being a close second.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to include where this was shown? Citing the evidence would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please provide evidence when you answer, so your claims can be verified.  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].